# How to set opacity or decrease brightness to div's background-image using CSS

Tags: html, css

In the following example only `background-color` displays but the image is not visible. The opacity also seems to be not working.

```css
.my-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
   
}
.my-container:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-image: url("https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/golden-retriever-dog-royalty-free-image-505534037-1565105327.jpg");
  background-position: 100% center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
        
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <p>Contents</p>
<div>
```

Comment: the opacity is very low, increase it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually works and image is visible, but you set `opacity: 0.1` and `background: blue` so it's barely visible. Just increase the opacity and maybe change `background-color` to more user friendly.

I cleaned up your code and placed content on top of image. In your example content has on image overlay which makes text harder to see.

```css
.my-container {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  font-size:2rem;
  color:#fff;
}

.my-container:before {
  content: '';
  
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
        
  opacity: 0.6;
        
  background-image: url("https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/golden-retriever-dog-royalty-free-image-505534037-1565105327.jpg");
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div id="content">CONTENT</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seemed to work just fine for me. I can see the picture when I set opacity: 0.5; And the blue background is still there. So I would suggest just raise your opacity
higher than 0.1. And see what looks best for you.

Answer (score -2):

Please use the css filter: brightness(80%); instead of opacity.

```
filter: brightness(50%);
```